# Wordpress stops rendering page after the_content()

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress appears to be giving up on building a page after `the_content()`.

I'm working on a theme that works perfectly on localhost (PHP v5.3) but when I push to the server (PHP v5.2), it will stop executing after the_content() on random pages and just close out with `</body>` and `</html>`.

Debug/display errors is enabled, but nothing shows up in browser or in the error log. The server and localhost's databases and files are identical.

Some pages display fine like they do on localhost, but others fail. There does not appear to be a difference between pages that fail and pages that render.

Examples: 
Page that renders correctly: http://sdi.ellcreative.com/technology-services/value-add-services/real-time-data-service/ 
Page that stops executing after the_content(): http://sdi.ellcreative.com/our-company/company-history/

I've tried using different content calls, and it still seems to fail at the same point. There is nothing special to the content of the pages, just straight up HTML.

Any ideas as to what is happening or what I can try?

Comment: What does the `error_log` say? Also, both pages end with `</body></html>`so `the_footer` is called. Maybe something is different in the content of those pages? Maybe a shortcode that fails or something similar? No one can know if you don't post more details.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Error log is clean. Yes, the pages end with </body></html>, but they should end with much more. If Wordpress is calling the_footer, then it is calling the default one and not my own.

Comment: There is no "default footer". `get_footer` (not `the_footer`, sorry) includes `footer.php` from your template (besides running other hooks and stuff) or nothing at all: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L54

Comment: Is your footer containing a menu? Make sure there's nothing in `functions.php` messing up with it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't have anything to do with `get_footer()`. The page itself has more to render (like closing tags for `<article>`, etc.). PHP/Wordpress seems to just give up and spit out `</body></html>` after `the_content()` is returned. Also: it works fine on localhost, but fails on random pages on the server. Files and databases are identical.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Also: for the "default footer" I was referring to the /wp-includes/theme-compat/footer.php file. However, it seems to be returning even less than what that file has in it.

Comment: Looking at the output more carefully I can see that the closing `</article>` is not sent to the browser either. Can you post the relevant part from your default page template?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37370/discussion-between-shshaw-and-sergiu-paraschiv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SergiuParaschiv helped me trace the issue to a custom filter for the footer  `add_filter('wp_footer', ...);` in `functions.php` that was causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a either an open tag (not closed properly), incorrectly closing a tag, or nested comments.

Check your source... if the source has all the content there and it's simply not rendered... it's not a wordpress problem but a content problem.